# Why is AWS telling me BucketAlreadyExists when it doesn't?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm in the process of automating the setup of some AWS services using AWS SDK for Python (boto3) and running into a very simple problem of creating an S3 bucket.

I've double-checked the following:

- In `~/.aws/credentials`, I have an Access Key ID and Secret Access Key set.
- This access key ID/secret access key is for an account that is part of a group with the following policy attached:

  ```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- There is no existing bucket with the name I'm trying to create the bucket with

Yet when I try to run this very simple operation, it fails:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> response = client.create_bucket('staging')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/yiqing/Repos/ansible-home/roles/osx/files/virtualenvs/obaku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 157, in _api_call
    "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
TypeError: create_bucket() only accepts keyword arguments.
>>> response = client.create_bucket(Bucket='staging')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/yiqing/Repos/ansible-home/roles/osx/files/virtualenvs/obaku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/yiqing/Repos/ansible-home/roles/osx/files/virtualenvs/obaku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 494, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (BucketAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
```

I feel like I'm missing something very silly but can't for the life of me think of what it might be or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A bucket name is global and not specific to your account.
So you need to choose a name that doesnt exist at all. I recommend using a prefix

Comment: Oh, I interpreted "shared by all users of the system" to mean the users in our account. Thank you, that was completely unexpected >_>

Comment: Not "global to region."  Just global.  The bucket namespace spans all S3 regions.

Comment: Complementary to this answer :  Always create a naming convention to identify individual AWS resources created, e.g. `team name-project name- name` . Without naming convention, it will be a management mess when multiple team and project sharing the same account.